# is there any way to clear the multiselect in MudDatagrid programmatically?

Tags: datagrid, mudblazor

If i multiselet the rows and reloaded the list of mudgrid, I seleted another row but still previously seleted rows also are coming(not in the view but when i using SelectedItemsChanged event, it provides previousely seleted data as well. each time i cleared seletion list as well before SelectedItemsChanged ).

If i multiselet the rows and reloaded the list of mudgrid, I seleted another row but still previously seleted rows also are coming(not in the view but when i using SelectedItemsChanged event, it provides previousely seleted data as well. each time i cleared seletion list as well before SelectedItemsChanged).

```
private void SelectedItemsChanged(HashSet<TestMain> selectedItems)
{
   lstSerialNo.Clear();

   if (selectedItems != null && selectedItems.Any())
   {
    lstSerialNo.AddRange(selectedItems.Select(x => new TestMain
        {
            isPin = x.isPin,
           
            StatusId = x.StatusId,
           
        }));

   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually reset the Selected Items when reloading the data.

Additionally to `SelectedItemsChanged` you can use `SelectedItems`. Which you can modify.

```
private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();
private HashSet<Element> SelectedElements = new HashSet<Element>();
```

Attribute SelectedItems on MudDataGrid:

```
<MudDataGrid T="Element" MultiSelection="true" Items="@Elements" SelectedItems="SelectedElements" SelectedItemsChanged="@SelectedItemsChanged">
```

Method to reload Data and reset selected Items

```
async Task ReloadData()
{
    // Reset SelectedElements
    SelectedElements = new HashSet<Element>();
    Elements = *FetchData*;
}
```

[MudSnippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GuQdvmlsRgaPWrPg)